# sshuttle produces python error

Tags: 16.04, ssh, python

I can connect to my server using ssh on my system and also using sshuttle on other systems. But when I try it on my 16.04 it produces following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "assembler.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "sshuttle.server", line 229, in main
  File "sshuttle.server", line 84, in list_routes
  File "sshuttle.server", line 63, in _list_routes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1153, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
client: fatal: server died with error code 1
```

My command is :
`sshuttle -r me@[myserverip] 0/0 -v`

What is the real problem. I guess it relates to package system and conflicts of deb packages. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: "`Cannot allocate memory`" message is interesting. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 16GB physical plus 16GB swap. It is lower than 10% when seeing top program. @N0rbert